# Generate Random Number of Jobs for Various HPC Workloads, Constrained by Resource Availability

Tags: python, random, statistics, distribution, allocation

### Overview

I am trying to use Python to generate a randomized distribution of resources for various HPC workloads, constrained by the resources available on the cluster.

For example:

- Type A = 4 cores, 8GB RAM
- Type B = 16 cores, 32GB RAM
- Type C = 32 cores, 128GB RAM

The cluster contains, say, 600 cores and 3000GB of RAM. Let's assume I want to have 50 concurrent users (or close to it).

### Example

One feasible situation would be:

```
n_users = 50
n_A = 30 # 120 cores, 240GB RAM
n_B = 10 # 160 cores, 320GB RAM
n_C = 10 # 320 cores, 1280GB RAM

# 120 + 160 + 320 <= 600 cores
# 240 + 320 + 1280 <= 3000GB RAM
```

### Questions

1. How can I generate randomized distributions of resource allocation, per machine type (A,B,C) for n-users without violating available resources?
2. How could I generate randomized distributions of resource allocation, per machine type, for *random number of users* but with fixed core-count? I.e. constraint is to use 500 cores.

### Thoughts

After thinking about this for a bit, my initial thought is to use a constrained stochastic optimizer method to generate pareto-optimal solutions (non violating combinations of workloads) and using that as my random set. Unless someone has a better idea.

### Update 1

I have a method working in which I generate `n_customer` number of machine instances, then do a simple `while` loop to check if resource constraints are violated. If violated, random machine is selected for instance reduction. This continues until no resource violations occur, and the actual customer number (total number of instances) is returned with the number of instances per type. **This works, but I am curious to see if someone has a cleaner method.**